# Kuzzle S3 plugin / Minio cant connect

Tags: amazon-s3, minio, kuzzle

I have the following Kuzzle S3 Plugin config:

```
"s3": {
  // AWS S3 bucket
  "bucketName": "chris",  // this is a bucket i created in Minio
  "endpoint": "http://10.0.0.66:9000",
  "s3ClientOptions": {
    "s3ForcePathStyle": false
  },
  "signedUrlTTL": 1200000,
  "redisPrefix": "s3Plugin/uploads"
},
```

I don't know if this config is correct. When I use the test file from
[kuzzleio/kuzzle-plugin-s3/blob/master/test/s3-upload-test.html](https://github.com/kuzzleio/kuzzle-plugin-s3/blob/master/test/s3-upload-test.html)

I get the following error

```
Uncaught (in promise) KuzzleError: Caught an unexpected plugin error: Inaccessible host: `chris.10.0.0.66'. This service may not be available in the `us-east-1' region. This is probably not a Kuzzle error, but a problem with a plugin implementation.
```

'chris.10.0.0.66' is an incorrect resource - as you can see, I'm not referencing this in the config.

[image]

The 10.0.0.66 is only accessible in my network.

Can someone help with this? Thank you much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok - so I found a working answer

```
"s3": {
  // AWS S3 bucket
  "bucketName": "chris",
  "endpoint": "http://10.0.0.66:9000",
  "s3ClientOptions": {
    "s3ForcePathStyle": true,
    "signatureVersion": "v4"
  },
  "signedUrlTTL": 1200000,
  "redisPrefix": "s3Plugin/uploads"
},
```

I modified the s3ClientOptions with:
"s3ClientOptions": {
"s3ForcePathStyle": true,  // must be true for Minio
"signatureVersion": "v4" // added this line
}

Source = https://docs.min.io/docs/how-to-use-aws-sdk-for-javascript-with-minio-server.html